# Hive: window function - how to exclude the CURRENT ROW

Tags: hive

I wish to calculate the minimum of a value over a partition, but the current row should not be taken into account.

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(val) OVER(PARTITION BY col1)
FROM table
```

outputs the minimum over all rows in the partition.

The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) shows ways to use CURRENT ROW, but not how to exclude it while performing the windowing operation.

I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(val) OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ROWS NOT CURRENT ROW)
FROM table
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way to do this.  The min over a window excluding the current row will always be the min over the window ***except*** when the row you are at is the min; then then min will be the 2nd min over the window.  Example:

**Data**:

```
-----------
key  |  val
-----------
1       8
1       2
1       4
1       6
1       11
2       3
2       5
2       7
2       9
```

**Query**:

```
select key, val, act_min, val_arr
  , case when act_min=val then val_arr[1] else act_min
    end as min_except_for_c_row
from (
  select key, val, act_min, sort_array(val_arr) val_arr
  from (
    select key, val
      , min(val) over (partition by key) act_min
      , collect_set(val) over (partition by key) val_arr
    from db.table ) A
  ) B
```

I left all the columns in for illustration.  You can modify the query as needed.

**Output**:

```
key val act_min val_arr         min_except_for_c_row
1   8   2       [2,4,6,8,11]    2
1   2   2       [2,4,6,8,11]    4
1   4   2       [2,4,6,8,11]    2
1   6   2       [2,4,6,8,11]    2
1   11  2       [2,4,6,8,11]    2
2   3   3       [3,5,7,9]       5
2   5   3       [3,5,7,9]       3
2   7   3       [3,5,7,9]       3
2   9   3       [3,5,7,9]       3
```